# Android: how to translate app into different languages and sell on marketplace?

Tags: android

Say I have an app consisting of some preference lists, some toasts, etc. Strings are set both in the XML files and appending/created dynamically in Java sometimes.

How does one go about making the app in like 8 different languages and selling them based on language? Does the android marketplace let you set a dropdown list for language to download in?

Also on the programming side, is having the translations in a word file and then doing copy-and-paste into eclipse going to work?

Perhaps I'm asking in the wrong place, but I'm not too sure where to start here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html) has everything you need to know.

Answer (score 7):

It's easy. Place your string resources in different XML files:

- res/values/strings.xml - for default
  language
- res/values/strings-de.xml for German
- res/values/strings-it.xml for Italian

and so on

Also you can put your layouts to different resources. Everything is described in links provided in other answers

Comment: Based on [this resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html), I don't think the qualifier should be added in the XML file itself, it should be in `values` folder which contains strings.xml file. It should be `values-de/strings.xml | values-it/strings.xml`.

Answer (score 3):

On localization I think you should read **[this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html#using-framework)**;

Maybe [**Market Filters**](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/market-filters.html) can help you with specifict target selling.

Answer (score 3):

Android has the excellent support for localization. [See the official reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html). [Here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/localization/index.html)  is good example.